# How to create an Object Model from Another?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to work with vehicles in my App, which can be of many kinds: trucks, vans, etc.

So, I made a model class of the base elements of the vehicle and some processes to work with the model, something like:

```
import 'dart:convert';

VehicleModel vehicleModelFromJson(String str) => VehicleModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String vehicleModelToJson(VehicleModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class VehicleModel {
    VehicleModel({
        this.model,
        this.licenseplate,
    });

    String? model;
    String? licenseplate;

    factory VehicleModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => VehicleModel(
        model: json["model"],
        licenseplate: json["licenseplate"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "model": model,
        "licenseplate": licenseplate,
    };
}
```

Now I want to make a new type of vehicle based on the old one. Suppose it is a truck, which has the same properties as a vehicle, and also has a load capacity. I read in [Exploring Inheritance and Composition in Dart](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/exploring-inheritance-and-composition-in-dart-flutter-71ceefc45c9c) that you simply have to make a class that inherits properties from the other, however I don't know how to do it

Based on this article, I tried to implement something like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:pathofmyapp/models/vehicle_model.dart';

TruckModel truckModelFromJson(String str) => TruckModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String truckModelToJson(TruckModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class TruckModel extends VehicleModel {
    TruckModel({
        this.model,
        this.licenseplate,
        this.loadingcapacity,
    }) : super (model: model, licenseplate: licenseplate);

    String? loadingcapacity;

    factory TruckModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TruckModel(
        model: json["model"],
        licenseplate: json["licenseplate"],
        loadingcapacity: json["loadingcapacity"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "model": model,
        "licenseplate": licenseplate,
        "loadingcapacity": loadingcapacity,
    };
}
```

But an error appears indicating that the `model` and `licenseplate` are not `a field in the enclosing class`. In toJson function appears a suggestion of type `Annotate overridden members`.

How can I create a Truck Object based on Vehicle Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `model` and `licenseplate` arguments have to be forwarded to the `super` constructor (which is already done in your code), but therefore the `this` keyword is misplaced in the `TruckModel` constructor (both fields are defined in the base class `VehicleModel`).

```
TruckModel truckModelFromJson(String str) => TruckModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String truckModelToJson(TruckModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class TruckModel extends VehicleModel {
    // Remove this keyword from the two fields model and licenseplate
    TruckModel({
        model,
        licenseplate,
        this.loadingcapacity,
    }) : super (model: model, licenseplate: licenseplate);

    String? loadingcapacity;

    factory TruckModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TruckModel(
        model: json["model"],
        licenseplate: json["licenseplate"],
        loadingcapacity: json["loadingcapacity"],
    );
    
    // Add @override since you are overwriting a method of the base class
    @override
    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "model": model,
        "licenseplate": licenseplate,
        "loadingcapacity": loadingcapacity,
    };
}
```